# Listening to textChanged from another application

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to know when a text from another application has changed?

Currently I can capture the `Click` event using globalhooks and `WindowFromPoint()`

Comment: We need more details about the application you want to snoop. Are you asking _in general_, then yes - if you're prepared to write a special in-memory debugger for each application framework. If you're asking about pre-made IPC for specific frameworks like WinForms and WPF then again _yes_ but the solution will be entirely different. And so on.

Comment: UI Automation [TextPattern.TextChangedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.textpattern.textchangedevent)

Comment: Its look like ManagedSpyLib do the job... i will make a test

Comment: @Jimi looks really nice! i will give a try too, thanks

Comment: You can recieve events, but the app will not working, use `SetWindowLongPtr` and set WndProc to your own.